# htaccess, do not show index controller in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have some redirects and urls that use the index controller

absolute or relative like this: www.domain/index/contact or just /index/contact

Can I strip out the index part with htaccess so I wil see www.domain/contact

*I only want this for the index controller*

**EDIT**

these are my rules that I already have

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
Options All -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
DirectoryIndex index.php 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L,QSA]
```

thanks in advance, Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).  It has many powerful options for rewriting URL's in your application based on the rules you set up.

For your specific case, you might have a rule in your `.htaccess` like the following:

```
RewriteRule /contact(.*)$ /index/contact$1 [L,QSA]
```

The above rule will rewrite all requests to the `/contact` path as if the caller had visited `/index/controller` instead.  Also, any additional path information will be captured and substituted in `$1` for the replacement.  The `QSA` flag tells the rewrite engine to pass the query strign along intact as well.

If you want to route all requests, say except for paths that start with `/static`, you might prefer a rule like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/static
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will ignore all URL's beginning with `/static` and pass everything else through your controller.

**UPDATED**

You do not need the `RewriteCond` lines...  Unless you specifically want to skip rule processing for real files and directories.  It also looks like you may have a syntax problem with the rewrite path.  Start with a very basic rewrite setup and expand from there as needed:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]  # use ? or / but not both
```

This will allow you to visit `/contact` in a browser while the server acts as if you visited `/index.php/contact` instead.  It will also ignore any requests directly to `index.php` files in case they end up in your code.

Comment: yes, that's why I wrote this post, isn't mod_rewrite synomycol to htaccess. I am currently zifting to all posts using search term "htaccess remove part url", but not a lot off helpfull information yet. I maybe able to use these in a condition request uri ^index, but I haven't completely figured it out yet.

Comment: oh, thanks, but I need reverse logic, because I want all actions off the index controller hide the index part, unless I have to write this for every action in the index controller. Or am I reversed in the way I think mod rewrite works?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "isn't mod_rewrite synomycol to htaccess."  Because `mod_rewrite` acts on the incoming request path, you will need to map those to your intended destination.  I have updated my answer in case it gives you more ideas.

Comment: `mod_rewrite` routes the incoming request to your actual file location.  It can be used to map full filesystem paths or for doing advanced URL rewriting.  For your example, all requests to `/contact` would be treated on the server as if they were called by `/index/contact`.  I believe this is what you want.

Comment: that is an complete answer I think, just this - can I loose the [L,QSA] part, IF THESE RULES ARE APPLIED AFTER?------RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: The `[L,QSA]` flags are only applied if the `RewriteRule` is matched.  I believe you want to keep them even if you add the `RewriteCond`'s.

Comment: thanks , I am testing it now but this was it I think.I will mark your answer.

Comment: It is not working yet, but that is because of the rules I already have, I edited my answer. I can figure this out I hope

Comment: I think I have to do this kind of logic in the php router. The way it works now, is that all requests are processed by index.php. It looks for a controller and if it can't find any it defaults to the indexcontroller, same goes for the actions and defaults to default action. I think I have to make an array with the names off the actions in the indexcontroller so it will look in the indexcontroller specificly if I want it to accept a url like domain/contact for wich a contact controller does not exist.

Comment: I think your last edit wil work, but the way this mvc works is that it has to go threw index.php otherwise no objects will be created or constants will be defined.